# "Tell Me" search bar with Office 2016

Tags: c++, qt, outlook, office365

Office 2016 was released with a very specific search box on the ribbon shown below (image from Microsoft blog). After a little research (took me a bloody while to even get the search terms right for google) I found that it uses intuitive language to find the commands fast. I wanted to implement something similar if not the same with my application. 
[Excel Ribbon "Tell Me"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QykRk.jpg)

I wanted to know how do I proceed to implement this. I understand there is a steep learning curve but I am looking for a place to start. Hopefully some examples, some libraries if there is something or some algorithms I may need to learn.

It was very difficult finding out what technology is used. I found another blog explaining the new features with perhaps a little extra information rather than just mentioning what it is. ["Tell Me uses a technique called word-wheeling, which enables it to start showing results as soon as you start typing. With every keystroke, the results are modified and refined."](http://www.spreadsheet1.com/microsoft-office-excel-tell-me-help.html)

Read so far:

blogs.office.com/2014/05/15/get-more-done-with-tell-me 

blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ukfe/2014/06/03/office-365-productivity-feature-get-more-done-with-tell-me/

So any help for me to start trying to implement this feature is appreciated. Just as a note I use C++ (Qt) but I guess to learn I wouldn't mind any language.

Comment: Since you mentioned Qt there is an example for google search http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-googlesuggest-example.html and perhaps you are searching for this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search

Comment: Thank you for the lead. Any chance there are examples? Do I have to index it all in a DB or a Text file would do?

Comment: I guess I will have to learn the "incremental search" algorithms and its implementation. From the [example] (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-googlesuggest-example.html)  The GSUGGEST_URL should be changed to an internal method